# Posts no longer show up on followers' walls

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

Our site relies heavily on Facebook to bring in traffic each day.

We used to post news items using FBGraph to our wall which would bring people to our site but since the recent change in Facebook's news feed, our posts no longer appear.

If I use Facebook as our page and manually create a post, it does show up on our follower's walls.

Can anyone advise?

```
PAGE_ID = # ... my page ID

ACCESS_TOKEN = # ... access token

def facebook_opts
@facebook_opts ||= {
  :name        => title,
  :link        => url,
  :picture     => thumbnail_url,
  :description => description,
  }
end

FacebookPagePost.new(PAGE_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN, facebook_opts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest creating a new app every month, that reeks of spam. it may end up getting you on the wrong side of an FB ban hammer :)

Your problem is probably related to the recent Facebook bug that is preventing many API based posts from reaching users' walls. this has been high rip for Facebook since around the first if the month...

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/151722701585098?browse=search_4e91e6ad141402289352614

Comment: The application itself shouldn't have any impact on the metrics, as it's only a different way of publishing posts. But we see about 20% boost from normal facebook traffic when we cycle applications, and it slowly drops during the next month. Could you explain why it would be considered as spam, as it's transparent to users?

Comment: Cycling applications, IPs, or any other way of identifying the source of a message is a common tool used by spammers to prevent service providers from stopping them. I'm not saying you are doing something that violates FBs policies (you may), but I am saying that it will look very fishy to anyone who deals with spam.

Answer (score 0):

This is largely due to the application you are using. If that application is only used to post to the page wall and has no visitors on it's own it's considered unpopular and the posts are not shown. 
The workaround I've found is to switch applications every month keeping the same name, and discard the old one.

EDIT: You can use the welcome tab application for posting on the page wall, as it already has plenty of visitors if you prefer not to switch applications.

EDIT 2: You should probably implement some sort of tracking for the traffic you get from facebook (custom links etc.) and use that as a metric, and not wall posts for individual users, where there are numerous reasons on why the posts might not appear.

Comment: I assume you have some sort of landing tab on your page, set as a default tab for people who are not fans. Usually it's just a photo or some text. If not, simply make one and use the application you created for it for posting on the page. That application will always have visitors and be counted as popular by Facebook.

Comment: I use the Ruby fb_graph library to add wall posts to our page from our Rails Application.

The authentication token to do this was obtained from my personal account using the approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516824/post-to-facebook-fan-page-wall-from-rails#answer-5533839

Comment: Hopefully that sheds a little more light on how this is working just now and could give a clue as to how I can improve my setup

Comment: Your setup is probably fine if it's worked so far. What I'm suggesting is to periodically replace the APP_ID and APP_SECRET you are using with a new application. It's best if you also use that application for a tab on your page, but not necessary. Just don't delete the old application, as that will delete all the posts you created from it.

Comment: Thanks DannyKK - I understand your suggestion but I'm not convinced that having to re-create apps every month is an ideal solution... I'll wait and see how they resolve the API bug first - thanks for your help :)